# Will looking up parent document cause an extra query call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, associations

I have two models.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_many :posts
end

class Post
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :comment, type: String

  embedded_in :user
end
```

Now let's say I get the first post of the first user, then later on I call for the user's name. Will this cause an extra query to be called or is the parent document apart of the post?

```
posts = User.first.posts

first_post = posts.first

# Will this line of code below initiate a query search for users?
users_name = first_post.user.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB, by design, only allows documents to be retrieved from only one collection at a time. So if a `Post` is in a collection separate from `Users`, then it would require two queries. While it is possible that a given document could be cached (making a second query unnecessary), assume two queries are made generally.

Some drivers for MongoDB attempt to gather multiple records for a single collection (like `Post`s for example) by using the `$in` operator. Also, uou can do some prefetching/caching using the Mongoid extras caching feature: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#caching.

When using embedded documents, the entire document is actually fetched in the query you show above, so a second query is not needed to get the name.

```
# the entire User object matching the statement is fetched (the first User)
posts = User.first.posts  
# nothing happens here ... just client side
first_post = posts.first

# No, this won't result in a second query, as the entire document was fetched
users_name = first_post.user.name
```

Comment: This is the case even with embedded documents? I was thinking that embedded documents are physically in the same location as the parent document. But I guess if I'm calling for the embedded documents the parent document is not carried over to a variable pointing to the embedded documents.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that! Added the detail -- it's all loaded at once, so there's no second query.